# Message does not show on both sockets socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io for my app and for private messaging I am using   `socket.to(privateId).emit('new message', {msg: data, user: socket.username});`It is sending message to private Id on receiving side my message displays but on sender socket message is not displaying. what am I doing wrong? Is there any other method to send message to sender id?

Comment: What does "but on sender socket message is not displaying" mean?  Sending a message sends it to the recipient, not to anyone else.  If you want something to show on the sender side, then you have to write code to show something on the sender side.

Comment: Try add an additional line of code `socket.to(privateId).broadcast.emit('new message', {msg: data, user: socket.username});`.

Comment: jfriend00 I am beginner sorry before I ask any silly question.when I emit same thing it shows on both sides sender's as well as receiver's.

Comment: vladimir-kovpak it is not working.